# detecting if user is logged in at different domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm developing a rails app that creates a widget that you can put on your website. When the widget is displayed (on a website with a different host) to a user who is logged in my app, I would like to display him some additional admin options.

What would be the best and easiest way to figure out if the user is logged in the app?

I was thinking of storing the IP when user logs in, and then compare the IP from the request that is sent to the widget controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the [Omniauth Railscast Episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth-revised) and have been using session variables and a SessionsController to create and destroy sessions when the user logs in and out.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    # create user if new user, or find user account if returning user.
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url # or wherever
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url # or wherever
  end

end
```

Then in the Application Controller,

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def current_user
     @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
   end
 end
```

You can then easily determine if a user is logged in or not via `if current_user`, or equivalently, if `session[:user_id]` is nil.

Comment: Does that approach work on different hosts? Are those session cookies accessible from different hosts?

Comment: session[:user_id] is accessible regardless of if you are on www.mydomain.com, www.mydomain.com/some_subpage, etc. They are accessible throughout the user's session on your entire application.

Answer (score 2):

IP could be deceptive. Try cookies.

Edit: not only in an actively deceptive manner (i.e. spoofing/Tor) but rather if two people are on separate sites from the same public IP, then you have a false correlation.